Close speed dial on back press flutter
I am using the flutter speed dial package to implement expandable FAB.
It is working fine. The only problem I have is that when I press on the back button with the speed dial open, it closes (puts it the background) and when I open the app again the speed dial is still open.
I would like the speed dial to close when I press on the back button without closing the app.
I have tried using PopScope without success as oppose to WillPopScope which is used in the example page of the package.
 return SpeedDial(
  activeIcon: Icons.close_rounded,
  backgroundColor: theme.colorScheme.primary,
  foregroundColor: theme.colorScheme.primary,
  overlayColor: Colors.black,
  overlayOpacity: 0.6,
  spaceBetweenChildren: 16,
  iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  icon: Icons.add_rounded,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(Sizes.sixteen))),
  children: [


could you please share a full example code?

Checkout the openCloseDial property in SpeedDial.
You can create a value notifier and assign it to the property and handle it in the WillPopScope.
var isDialOpen = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

SpeedDial(
  ...
  openCloseDial: isDialOpen
  ...
)

In your PopScope, you can do this:
onWillPop: () async {
    if (isDialOpen.value) {
      isDialOpen.value = false;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },


If you are using Go_Router keep in mind that PopScope wont't work instead you can use BackButtonListener
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackButtonListener-class.html
Use Example:
 BackButtonListener(
  onBackButtonPressed: () async {
    print('test');
    return true;
  },
  child: SomeWidgets(),
);

